# How to Suppress ASCII Code Rendering?

Tags: php

Writing PHP code for an online forum.

Want to stop people from inserting ASCII characters and having them colorfully render in the finished page.

☂ ☺ ☹ ☃ ✉ ✿ ✄ ✈  ☔ ⚡ ❆ ☽ ☾ ✆ ✔ ☯ ☮

Is there a way to suppress this via PHP?  Or, some other method?

Thanks!

Comment: Those aren't ASCII codes

Comment: This isn't really a PHP or programming question, at least not yet.  You need to go to the support forum for your forum software and ask about the settings / options there.  "BBCode" or "emoji" or possibly Unicode filtering settings.  This might eventually become a PHP question if they suggest something for you to write in PHP and you have trouble getting it to work.